# How to know if RDDs in a spark streaming window has finished the spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am reading messages from Kafka in a Spark Streaming application.

SparkBatch duration:15 sec. 
SparkWindow: 60 Sec.

```
var dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() // ignore the argumtns
var windowedStream = dstream.window(SparkWindow)
// delete data from REDIS
windowedStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                JavaFutureAction<Void> v = rdd.foreachPartitionAsync(t -> {
                // collect error data across partitions and write those to REDIS
        })// foreachPartitionAsync ends
    }
})
// fetchFromREDISAndProcess() --Once foreachRDD ends. fetch error data from REDIS and process them
```

There is a contraints that I have to first collect error records from each partitions & RDDs in a spark window then process them on driver.

I will get 4 RDDs in each Spark Window.

Problem:
 I want to read data from REDIS after each window and process them before proceeding t next window. Is there a way to ensure I execute my code everytime spark window ends?

Comment: did you check https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic for that:::

```
var dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() // ignore the argumtns
var windowedStream = dstream.window(SparkWindow)
// delete data from REDIS
var partitions = 4;
var currentPart = 0;

windowedStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                JavaFutureAction<Void> v = rdd.foreachPartitionAsync(t -> {
                // collect error data across partitions and write those to REDIS
        })// foreachPartitionAsync ends

        if(++currentPart % partitions == 0)    //It will be true at every 4th RDD where window will end.
            //Read data from REDIS and process here as after this new window will start.
    }
})
// fetchFromREDISAndProcess() --Once foreachRDD ends. fetch error data from REDIS and process them
```